# Looking for an example of sequence of analytic functions with weird behaviour

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

Denote by $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disk of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and let $D = \{z_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a dense set on $\mathbb{D}$. I'm looking for a sequence of analytic functions $(f_n)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that converges uniformly to an analytic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, converges pointwise on the dense set $D$ but does not converge on $\mathbb{D}\smallsetminus D.$ Can we construct such an example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if $f_n$ converges uniformly on $|z|=2$ then it does so on $|z|\le 2$.

$$\sup_{|z|\le 2} |f_n(z)-f_m(z)|\le \sup_{|z|=2} |f_n(z)-f_m(z)|$$

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!! I see the solution depends on the fact that we are considering entire functions. What could you say if we consider f_n to be analytic at |z|>1/2, it converges uniformly if |z|>1 and converges on a dense sequence on 1/2<|z|<1? I think you cannot use the same argument here...

Comment: You meant converges locally uniformly ? Take $a_j$ a dense sequence in $1/2<|z|<1$, let $f_n(z)=z^{-k_n}\prod_{j\le n} (z-a_j)$ with $k_n$ large enough so that $|f_n(z)|\le 1/n$ for $|z|>1+1/n$.

Comment: I mean uniform convergence on compact sets, I'm not sure if you get it with your example

Comment: ie. local uniform convergence, of course you do, on $|z|>1$